# CMake error: linker command failed with exit code 1 and cpp.o files

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, cmake, linker-errors

I am using CMake to compile a small project.

Here is what I have written in CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
project(DAF)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)


include_directories(include)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )


file(GLOB Src_Sources "src/*.cpp")
file(GLOB Test_Sources "test/*.cpp")


add_executable(executable ${Src_Sources} ${Test_Sources})

target_link_libraries( executable include ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

I have two directories src and test. The src directory contains only the files that hold the functions, whereas the test directory contains the main file.

Once I use the `cmake` command and then the `make` command I get this error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target executation
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/executation.dir/src/image.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/executation.dir/test/starter_1.cpp.o
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable executation
ld: library not found for -linclude
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [executation] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/executation.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So what I find strange is that it creates `.cpp.o` files. Is that normal?

And then how do I fix the error `library not found for -linclude`?

Comment: The bug is the `include` in this line: `target_link_libraries( executable include ${OpenCV_LIBS} )`

Comment: @drescherjm What do you recommend I do instead?

Comment: Remove the `include`. Instead do this: `target_link_libraries( executable ${OpenCV_LIBS} )`

Comment: @drescherjm It worked, thank you! You can write it as an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is normal for CMake to take the name of the source file, and append a `.o` when compiling the respective object files. For example, the source file `image.cpp` will be compiled into `image.cpp.o`. The Makefiles generated by CMake will contain a unique target `<someSourceFileName>.o` for each source file, where `<someSourceFileName>` can be a `.cc`, `.cpp`, `.c`, etc.

The error:

> ```
> ld: library not found for -linclude
> ```

indicates that you have tried to link a library called `include` to the executable. This is likely not what you intend. It appears `include` is actually your include directory, and you have already specified the include directories in your CMake with this line:

```
include_directories(include)
```

To remove the error, just take out the `include` from the [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) command, like so:

```
target_link_libraries( executable ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```